# Swapping nodes in a singly linked list java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have been trying to come up with an algorithm to swap 2 nodes (not necesarily right next to each other) in a singly linked list for 2 days but for some reason I cannot do it.
Here is what I have, I am really new to coding and have been really stressed:
[image]
I have managed to place a temp node in but can't actually swap the nodes.

```
public void swap(int i, int j) {
    current = head;
    current2 = head;
    sllNode temp = new sllNode(" ");
    sllNode temp2 = new sllNode(" ");

    for(int z = 0; i>z; z++)
        current=current.next;
    for(int q = 0; j>q; q++)
        current2 = current2.next;

    temp.next = current2.next.next;
    current.next = temp;
    current.next = current2.next.next;
    current2.next = current;
```

Comment: Include your code in the question please.

Comment: Please do not post your code as image!

Comment: To swap two of anything, a and b, you must do something like the following. `tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;`

Answer (score 3):

Why exchange nodes, when you can exchange the data?

```
public void swap(int i, int j) {

    sllNode ithNode = head;
    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
        ithNode = ithNode.next;
    }

    sllNode jthNode = head;
    for (int q = 0; q < j; q++) {
        jthNode = jthNode.next;
    }

    // Swap the data        
    String data = ithNode.data;
    ithNode.data = jthNode.data;
    jthNode.data = data;
}
```

It would make sense to use a method:

```
public sllNode get(int i) {
    sllNode current = head;
    while (i > 0) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    return current;
}
```

By the way:

- The convention for class names is a beginning capital: `SllNode`.
- Do not use fields for things like `current` and `current2` where they can be local variables.

---

***Exchanging nodes, the hard way***

Here one has to think, so it is best to deal with special cases first, and then only treat `i < j`.

```
public void swap(int i, int j) {
    if (i >= size() || j >= size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if (i == j) {
        return;
    }
    if (j < i) {
        swap(j, i);
        return;
    }

    // i < j

    sllNode ithPredecessor = null;
    sllNode ithNode = head;
    for (int z = 0; z < i; z++) {
        ithPredecessor = ithNode;
        ithNode = ithNode.next;
    }

    sllNode jthPredecessor = ithNode;
    sllNode jthNode = ithNode.next;
    for (int q = i + 1; q < j; q++) {
        jthPredecessor = jthNode;
        jthNode = jthNode.next;
    }

    // Relink both nodes in the list:

    // - The jthNode:
    if (ithPredecessor == null) {
        head = jthNode;
    } else {
        ithPredecessor.next = jthNode;
    }
    sllNode jNext = jthNode.next;
    //if (ithNode.next == jthNode) {
    if (jthPredecessor == ithNode) {
        jthNode.next = ithNode;
    } else {
        jthNode.next = ithNode.next;
    }

    // - The ithNode:
    if (jthPredecessor == ithNode) {
    } else {
        jthPredecessor.next = ithNode;
    }
    ithNode.next = jNext;
}
```

No guarantee that the logic is okay. There are tricks:

```
    //if (ithNode.next == jthNode) {
    if (jthPredecessor == ithNode) {
```

Both conditions test whether `i + 1 == j`, but testing on a .next and then assigning makes the condition a momentary state. As you see it would have been easier to have one single `if (i + 1 == j) { ... } else { ... }` and handle both the ithNode and jthNode.

Comment: Part of the reason I want to exchange the nodes is because I am trying to gain a deeper understanding of nodes. I know it may not be the most effective method but I care more about the understanding for now.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to swap 2 things: the node as next from the previous node, and the next node.

Once you found `current` and `current2` which are the previous nodes of the nodes you want to swap, do this:

Swap the nodes:

```
sllNode tmp = current.next;
current.next = current2.next;
current2.next = tmp;
```

Then swap the next:

```
tmp = current.next.next;
current.next.next = current2.next.next;
current2.next.next = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

// Swapping two elements in a Linked List using  Java

import java.util.*;

class SwappingTwoElements {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>();

    // Adding elements to Linked List
    ll.add(10);
    ll.add(11);
    ll.add(12);
    ll.add(13);
    ll.add(14);
    ll.add(15);

    // Elements to swap
    int element1 = 11;
    int element2 = 14;

    System.out.println("Linked List Before Swapping :-");

    for (int i : ll) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

    // Swapping the elements
    swap(ll, element1, element2);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Linked List After Swapping :-");

    for (int i : ll) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}

// Swap Function
public static void swap(LinkedList<Integer> list,
                        int ele1, int ele2)
{

    // Getting the positions of the elements
    int index1 = list.indexOf(ele1);
    int index2 = list.indexOf(ele2);

    // Returning if the element is not present in the
    // LinkedList
    if (index1 == -1 || index2 == -1) {
        return;
    }

    // Swapping the elements
    list.set(index1, ele2);
    list.set(index2, ele1);
}
```

}
Output
Before Swapping Linked List  :-
10 11 12 13 14 15

After Swapping Linked List  :-
10 14 12 13 11 15
Time Complexity: O(N), where N is the  Linked List length